# HTML / CSS - Custom made image border

Tags: html, css

First of all, I would like to point out that I'm somewhat new to CSS :)

I'm trying to make a custom image border around an image, but I just can't figure out where did it all went wrong.

Basically, I need to make this happen:

[Pic of the final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtmxY.jpg)

, and this is the code that I came up with:

```
<div class="AboutMeImage">
<a href="https://s22.postimg.org/ma6wrg5r5/girl-in-winter.jpg">
<img class="test-img img-responsive" src="https://s22.postimg.org/ma6wrg5r5/girl-in-winter.jpg" alt="test photo" />
 </a>
</div>


.AboutMeImage {
clear: both;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: auto;
width: 40%;
}

.test_img {
border: 10px solid transparent;
border-image: url(https://s24.postimg.org/tpxcnhk51/image_holder1.png) 602 774 0 0 stretch;
```

}

```
.img-responsive {
display: block;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/KC87/956purro/6/

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all your class name is wrong in css, in html you have **test-img** and in css you are writing it as **test_img**

Please apply this style.

```
.test-img {
  border: 10px solid #3778ff;
  height: 40vh;
  border-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/652/pink-doily-bdr.png") 30;
  }
```

working Example

https://jsfiddle.net/bilawalkhan/956purro/9/

Comment: Sorry about that, just a typo (next time "copy/paste" method :)
your example is AWESOME! is it possible to make the border show on top of the image (like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtmxY.jpg) so that the image is visible "through out" the border?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below modified code..You can customize the border more according to your need.[Click to view the code](https://jsfiddle.net/956purro/10/)

```
img {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  outline-offset: -4px;
}
```